# Meaning of `.*` in python's regex module - I thought it means any number of anything?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Something peculiar is happening to me.  For a long time I thought that `.*` meant any number of any character, including nothing at all.  I have two examples which give different results:

## Example 1

This example prints as I expect:

```
string_2 = 'SomethingStuff stuff1 ' 
my_regex = '(stuff)'
match_object = re.findall(my_regex, string_2, flags=re.I)
print match_object
```

Output:

```
['Stuff', 'stuff']
```

## Example 2

This example should print the same, as I currently understand `.*`, but it doesn't:

```
string_2 = 'SomethingStuff stuff1 '
my_regex = '(stuff).*'    # notice the difference here
match_object = re.findall(my_regex, string_2, flags=re.I)
print match_object
```

Output:

```
['Stuff']
```

Why are these different?  It really bothers me....

Answer (score 3):

Because of the capturing group `(...)` you used in the regex, `re.findall` should print the charcaters which are matched by the pattern present inside the capturing group. Note that `re.findall` should give the first preference to groups and then for matches. Since, `Stuff` in your regex present in the group and the following `.*` matches all the characters upto the last (*it includes  second `stuff` also*), your regex should print only the first `Stuff`. If you remove the group, it should print all the chracaters from the first `stuff` to the last.

```
>>> string_2 = 'SomethingStuff stuff1 '
>>> re.findall('stuff.*', string_2, flags=re.I)
['Stuff stuff1 ']
```

Comment: what is the difference between a group and a match in this case?

Comment: what i mean by group is, `foo(bar)` regex in `re.findall`should print only  `bar` but `foobar` regex in `re.findall` should print `foobar` . So if there is any group present `(..)` then `findall` gives the 1st prefer to group so that it prints `bar` only in the first example. In the second ex, there are no gruoups, so it spits out all the matches.

Comment: ....hm, but it seems to me like there are groups in both of my examples, i.e. there are `(...)`  in both examples.  And, your code doesn't do what I want to do though, because I wanted to have a __list__ of `stuff`'s.  Not just a string of them.

Comment: How do I capture every instance of `stuff`?

Comment: Yeah, that is logically equivalent to @TigerhawkT3 answer.

Comment: @Hunle don't know the diff between `stff` and `stuff.*?`

Comment: Eh, maybe not?  Enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the `.*`: that matches everything, and it will keep consuming the string until there's nothing left. If you want it to stop and not consume the next `'stuff'`, use a question mark to indicate a non-greedy match:

```
>>> string_2 = 'SomethingStuff stuff1 '
>>> my_regex = '(stuff).*'    # notice the difference here
>>> match_object = re.findall(my_regex, string_2, flags=re.I)
>>> print (match_object)
['Stuff']
>>> my_regex = '(stuff).*?'    # notice the difference here
>>> match_object = re.findall(my_regex, string_2, flags=re.I)
>>> print (match_object)
['Stuff', 'stuff']
```